# Show number of answers when question is expanded in /review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

When I'm looking at the "First Questions" review tab, each question shows the number of answers and the accepted/not accepted state. After I click the "review question" link, the question is expanded but now I can't see the answer information anymore.

I find that by the time I'm done reading the question, I sometimes want to leave a clarifying comment. By then I forget if the question was already answered and some comments are completely pointless if the question got an accepted answer hours ago, for example.

I'm not sure if there's a good way to do it, but can the answer information still be displayed somehow after the question is expanded in /review? Maybe after the question title?

Alternatively, being able to collapse the question again and return to the original view would work too.